# What is "snd_ducking_off" command?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

`snd_ducking_off` audio command can be found some [high-profile autoexec files](https://gist.github.com/nickbudi/3916475). How does setting `snd_ducking_off` to `1` change audio?

Comment: Are you asking what `snd_ducking_off` is or what setting it to 1 does?

Comment: @TimmyJim Honestly, I think both those answers are pretty much wrapped in the answer to what "snd\_ducking\_off" is (assuming it does actually change audio).

Comment: @TimmyJim: Both.

Comment: I'm no longer sure what is the default value, `1` or `0`.

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess I would say that it is probably 0 by default.  Primarily because having you turn on an option to turn off a feature makes it sound like the option to bypass the feature was put in after the feature was already a thing.  Ducking is also generally a usability feature to make things better sounding in general, but competitive players may not want the brief loss of audio information that lowered sound causes much like many competitive players lower graphical settings in various games to make things easier to spot with less visual noise.

Answer (score 4):

[Ducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ducking) audio is when the volume of other tracks/present audio is lowered on the introduction of a new audio track to make it stand out.  This can be done for a variety of reasons in games, such as to have voice chat/communications be able to be heard regardless of other things going on or to make things like gunfire/explosions stand out more without having to go crazy with volume (and allowing your "normal" hearing to blend back in).

It is likely that if snd_ducking_off is set to 1 that this effect will not be applied and the background audio in situations where the audio would normally be ducked will remain at full volume.